# Excel-Formula: How to add two columns in an excel show the result in the third for the entire column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to add values of column `E` and `F` and subtract values from `G` and show the result in `H`.

So its like

The column H will be having `H(i) = E(i) + F(i) - G(i)`

Comment: Is this related to programming ? Just type in cell Hx '=Ex+Fx-Gx' and replace 'x' with the proper row number.

Comment: How is this related to programming? :) It looks like more into specific software usage (MS Excel).

Comment: Also, you are getting -1's because 1) your question does not seem related to programming at all 2) it shows you have no clue whatsoever how to achieve this task which is a requirement around here.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur You are right. 1) This is not related to programming. 2) I did not have any clue about how to get this done. I thought to add a tag ms-excel, but its not there. I really don;t mind getting -1s as far as it solves my problem. Thank you for the heads up though. Appreciate it.

Comment: @webExplorer: `Excel` is the right tag :) You just missed one extra tag which is `Excel-Formula`. I already added that for you.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur: I agree with your point 2 but not with your point 1 :) Formula Based questions are not OFFTOPIC as per this [RECENT](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199823/slight-amendment-to-close-reason) post in Meta. Damn! I got so many downvotes on that LOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for a formula such as this to be placed in the top of your column of calculations:

```
Cell H1:
=(E1+F1)-G1
```

You can adjust this accordingly depending on where your calculations start in Column H (i.e. cell H10).

Cheers.

Comment: Yes, I thought it will be that simple. I think I just had to write the rule in 1st row and drag it till the last row. Thanks!